# Why doesn't whitespace act as a delimiter when printing strings with ostream operator<<?

Tags: c++, string, iostream, delimiter

I know that when writing code like `std::cin >> some_var;` , where some_var is a string variable, only the first word that was inputted will be stored in `some_var`. But I do not understand why `std::cout << "something here";` does not only output "something". Am I missing something?

Comment: It is hard to answer this other than "that is the way they are defined to behave".  The output operator copies the entire string to output; the input reads one word.  This is equivalent to the asymmetric behaviour of the `%s` format specifier in `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: Because people don't want to print things one word at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reading input using `cin >> some_var`, the delimiter is *space* by default  (you *can* change this though), while when printing, `cout` prints till its find `\0` which is end of the string.

If you want to read till it finds `\0` in the input stream, then you've to write this:

```
std::getline(std::cin, some_var, '\0');
```

You can give any other character as *delimiter* as third argument of `std::getline` function.

Note that there is a member function with same name `getline` which is slightly different than the one I used above which is a free standalone function.

Compare:

- [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) - free standalone function. An overloaded function is also available.
- [istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) - member function of `std::istream`

I used the first one.

Comment: This is the answer that makes the most technical sense :)

Comment: That is a good description of _how_ but you haven't provided any of the _why_.

Answer (score 4):

It was deemed useful that `cin`, when reading into a `string` terminates at whitespace. But it wasn't deemed useful that only the first word is printed when you print a string.

After all you said *print "something here" to cout*· In the other case, you just said *read something from `cin`*. The choice between a word, between a line and between the whole content of *stdin* (until an EOF is received) is arbitrary and the design happens to be to read a word. That makes it easy to quickly read a record line like "john 10 2.15" (first read into string, then into an int, and then into a float). Use `std::getline` to read a whole line into a `string`.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you take input from `std::cin`, it needs to know when to *stop* taking input. If it didn't stop at the first word, when *would* it stop? However, when you *output* a variable, the answer is easy- you output that one variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... `cin` stops at a space because, by default, it thinks you want a word. `cout` doesn't follow the same restriction, because, well, why would it? Think about it for a second — would it make any sense whatsoever if printing out "Hello, world!" actually just printed out "Hello,"? Of course it doesn't make any sense. The developer knows what they want to output (at least, we hope :D).

Answer (score 1):

I think they took a convention and stick to it. In the case of `<<`, it is clear that you specify what to be written. In the case of a `>>`, they have to decide where to stop. Newline? Maybe this is the most natural alternative, but they just decided to stop reading at a space.

Answer (score -1):

The delimiters are different for `cin` and for `cout`. For `cin`, input is split at whitespaces, for `cout`, at end of lines. You can change those default delimiters though.

Comment: `cout` stops at the NUL `'\0'`, not newline.